# How to Access local variable of the method from one class to another

Tags: java

```
public void processVmCreate(SimEvent ev) {
    int[] data = (int[]) ev.getData();
    int datacenterId = data[0];
    int vmId = data[1];
    int result = data[2];
}
```

I want to access the local variable of method `processVmCreate(SimEvent ev)`
in another class that is in another package. How can i access?

Comment: Local variables are, well, local. You can't access them from anywhere else, same package or not. Only the method itself can access them.

Comment: are you referring to the last three local variables of the said method or a _specific_ one?

Comment: i want to use vm id ..

Comment: VmList.getById(getVmsCreatedList(),vmId).getHost().getId()
when i use this statement for printing hostID for the required vm i get back error on vmid for its declaration.but vmid declaration is in diffent method also in different package..also vmid is local in that pakage

Answer (score 0):

Local variables die after the method execution is done.

If you want to use them in other method, your choices are :

1) Pass to that method, assuming you calling that method here (u*sing it's instance may be or with in the same class method*).

2) Creating static variable and assign here , so it avail there. But make sure that you call this method before using it. but I prefer the first. Unless you have no option choose the static.

Comment: VmList.getById(getVmsCreatedList(),vmId).getHost().getId() when i use this statement for printing hostID for the required vm i get back error on vmid for its declaration.but vmid declaration is in diffent method also in different package..also vmid is local in that pakage

Answer (score 0):

To get your results from another class, you can :

1 - Declare them as global attributes and access to them by their getters like this:

```
public class YourClass {

    int datacenterId = -1;
    int vmId = -1;
    int result = -1;


    public void processVmCreate(SimEvent ev) {
        int[] data = (int[]) ev.getData();
        datacenterId = data[0];
        vmId = data[1];
        result = data[2];
    }

    public int getDatacenterId() {
        return datacenterId;
    }


    public int getVmId() {
        return vmId;
    }

    public int getResult() {
        return result;
    }

}
```

2- Or you can transform your method like this and let it return a hashMap :

```
   public HashMap<String, Integer>  processVmCreate(SimEvent ev) {
        int[] data = (int[]) ev.getData();
        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>() ; 
        map.put("datacenterId", data[0]) ;
        map.put("vmId", data[1]) ;
        map.put("result", data[2]) ;
        return map ;
    }
```

And from another class you can access to your attributs like this :

```
 public class AnotherClass {
         //other code 
        public void anotherMethod(){
            YourClass yourClass = new YourClass() ;
            int datacenterId = yourClass.processVmCreate(simEvent).get("datacenterId") ;
            int vmId yourClass.processVmCreate(simEvent).get("vmId") ;
            int result yourClass.processVmCreate(simEvent).get("result") ;

        }
    }
```

Unless , you can not access to **local** variable from **another** class **because they are local**

Answer (score -1):

You can make the variables global but change the access to private and make their getter and setter methods then access them in other class.

Comment: This question doesn't answer the question. OP is asking about local variables in a method, not members of a class.